# vl_sift Why two frames have the same position

Tags: sift, vlfeat

I am a freshman of vl_sift. When I ran the codes from the [website](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html), I have found a problem which I didn't understand.
After executing `[f,d] = vl_sift(I) ;` I checked the `f`.

```
col   11                      12       

15.6534681320190    15.6534681320190
315.868621826172    315.868621826172
1.75902485847473    1.75902485847473
0.729515715938409   -2.98263351880919
```

Two columns have the same values of `X,Y` but different orientations. What's the mean?
Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function that computes the orientation of a given keypoint can indeed compute **multiple** orientations. In practice vlfeat can return up to 4 orientations for the same keypoint:

- [SIFT vlfeat documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html#sift-tech-detector-orientation)
- [vl_sift_calc_keypoint_orientations](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift_8c.html#a2e409d464f81582dc3e839bf0fece66e)

For more details, please refer to the section *5. Orientation assignment* of the [original paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf):

> Peaks in the orientation histogram correspond to dominant directions of local gradients [...] for locations with multiple peaks of similar magnitude, there will be multiple keypoints created at the same location and scale but different orientations.

Comment: I wonder that one pixel corresponds to just only one vector of descriptor ,or two?I might not totally understand SIFT Algorithm.Thanks a lot!